# Issue in closing navigation drawer when click on Expendable menu item

Tags: android, expandablelistview, drawerlayout

I am getting an issue when I try to close the navigation drawer by on click method on its item of the expandable list menu.

Here is the method of expandable list view menu of the navigation drawer, where the menu title is getting binded and on submenu item click new MainActivity().closeDrawer() is called and throws an error.

```
 @Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final String childData = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_submenu, null);
    }

    String[] str = childData.split("@");

    final TextView txtListChildTitle = convertView.findViewById(R.id.submenu);

    txtListChildTitle.setText(str[0]);
    txtListChildTitle.setTag(str[1]);

    txtListChildTitle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            new MainActivity().closeDrawer();
            String tag = txtListChildTitle.getTag().toString();
            Intent i2 = new Intent(mContext, AllSubCategory.class);
            i2.putExtra("ID", tag);
            mContext.startActivity(i2);
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

here is the error

```
2019-09-20 11:53:27.037 7717-7717/com.techabilit.readerchoice E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.techabilit.readerchoice, PID: 7717
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout.closeDrawer(int)' on a null object reference
    at com.techabilit.readerchoice.Activities.MainActivity.closeDrawer(MainActivity.java:821)
```

and here is the close drawer method at MainActivity.java:821

```
public void closeDrawer() {

    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

}
```

please help me out to close the drawer by onClick of the nav menu subitem.

Comment: Follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45878902/how-to-close-navigation-drawer-from-an-adapter-class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue is here.

```
new MainActivity().closeDrawer();
```

Replace with

```
((MainActivity)mContext).closeDrawer();
```

You are creating the new instance of the `MainActivity` every time when you click on the item. Instead of that you can cast the `mContext` to the `MainActivity` and call the `closeDrawer()`.

Comment: @RahulPathak,  If the issue is fixed then, please mark as accepted. So, that it can be helpful to others.

Answer (score 1):

new mainActivity() will create another  instance of class which is not same for the instance you are working so please try once please try **context.closeDrawer();**